# laravel ajax append doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

here is my code for ajax. I am using laravel 5.4 and I don't know the problem why the append doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('change','#product_category',function(){
         var cat_id = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
             type:'get',
             url:'{!!URL::to('findProductName')!!}',
             data:{'id':cat_id},
             success:function(data){
             console.log('success');
             console.log(data);
             //console.log(data.length);
             var op = "";
             op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>Choose Product</option>';
             for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
             }
             var div = $(this).parent();
             div.find('.choice').html(" ");
             div.find('.choice').html(op);
           },
           error:function(){
           }
         });
      });
 });
```

Comment: First of all your ajax get success ? and show your html too

Comment: yes i get a success

Comment: This piece of code is hardcoded inside a blade template inside <script> tag?

Comment: is there any error in console ?  show your relevant part of html too

Answer (score 1):

Mistake in a first look found here

```
url:"{!!URL::to('findProductName')!!}",
```

Quotes mistake

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables to a JavaScript script you should assign the value to a global variable **before** you load the actual ajax script.

Into the blade template:

```html
<script>
  var toUrl = "{!! URL::to('findProductName') !!}";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/ajax/script.js"></script>
```

then in your script you can do the following:

```
{
  ...
  url: toUrl,
  ...
}
```

or you could use a laravel library to bind JavaScript values to a view like [Transform PHP Vars to JavaScript](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)

Answer (score 0):

put

```
$ajax({
...
async : false
..})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain why this solves the problem?